# Connecting a Worklight JMS Adapter to Websphere MQ Server

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mq, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am getting the below error while invoking a JMS adapter(connects to Websphere MQ Server)
"JMS connection exception received: null. Closing the connection"

Please see below configurations (initialContextFactory, connectionFactory and destination)
**MQJMSAdapter.xml**

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="jms:JMSConnectionPolicyType">
        <!-- uncomment this if you want to use an external JNDI  repository -->
        <namingConnection url="file:/C:/JNDI-DIRECTORY/"
            initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"
        />
        <jmsConnection
            connectionFactory="myCF"
        />
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="10"/>
</connectivity>
```

I have installed and configured IBM Websphere MQ  server in my local machine and followed below guide to configure the JNDI namesapce and administered objects

```
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodconn/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.scenarios.wmqwasmig2v7.doc%2Ftopics%2Fins_sample.htm
```

Kindly give your inputs. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please post the full exception stack?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting this error message only in worklight development server console

Comment: What version of worklight are you using?

Comment: Worklight 6.1 and Websphere MQ server 7.5

Comment: Could we get a little more context around the exception message. it's not clear what exactly is going on

Comment: @Nagendra, Planning on replying any time soon? Was this resolved?

Comment: Not resolved and at present, I was taken a break to work on Worklight due to other priority ones...thanks @IdanAdar